# react native : Unable to uncheck checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

In my example I present a checkboxes list but
I cant uncheck the checkboxes.
Now I can only check them but cant uncheck .
How should I fix **MY code** that it will works fine ? ?

```
 const [checkList, setCheckList] = useState<any[]>(actionList.map(e => ({ key: e.key, checked: false })));
  const isChecked = (key) => {
    checkList.filter(e => e.key == key)[0].checked
  }


  const renderActionItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={index}
        activeOpacity={.7}
        style={styles.touchableOpacity}
        onPress={() => { console.log(item) }}
      >
        <CheckBox
          style={styles.checkBox}
          tintColors={{ true: 'white', false: 'white' }}
          value={isChecked(item.key)}
          onValueChange={() => {
            const newCheckList = checkList.slice()
            newCheckList.forEach(e => {
              if (e.key == item.key) {
                e.checked = !e.checked
              }
            })
            setCheckList(newCheckList)
          }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.labelText}>{`${item.sequenceID} . ${item.label}`}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
```

Comment: You have to add a return `return  checkList.filter(e => e.key == key)[0].checked;`

Comment: show me how your idea into my code..

Comment: `const isChecked = (key) => {
    return checkList.filter(e => e.key == key)[0].checked
  }`

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'native-base';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

class Row extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checked: false };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <CheckBox
          onPress={() => this.setState({
            checked: !this.state.checked
          })}
          checked={this.state.checked}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          { props.data }
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Row;
```

Comment: I ask how to change my code and not new code idea.

Comment: Lacks explanation.

Comment: its not works for me .
just take my code above and make the changes that it will works .
i dont need all the examples that you write here.. i just want fix my code thats all my friend .

Answer (score 0):

just use states to manage your item like this:

```
const renderActionItem = ({ item, index }) => {
const [checkbox, setCheckbox] = useState(false);
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={index}
        activeOpacity={.7}
        style={styles.touchableOpacity}
        onPress={() => { console.log(item) }}
      >
        <CheckBox
          style={styles.checkBox}
          tintColors={{ true: 'white', false: 'white' }}
          value={isChecked(item.key)}
          onValueChange={() => {
            useState(!checkbox)
          }}
        />
        <Text style={styles.labelText}>{`${item.sequenceID} . ${item.label}`}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
```

and then set a custom check icon depending on state change. alternatively, you can follow this example: note that im using SelectMultiple instead of checkbox in this case

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import SelectMultiple from 'react-native-select-multiple'

const fruits = ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears']
// --- OR ---
// const fruits = [
//   { label: 'Apples', value: 'appls' },
//   { label: 'Oranges', value: 'orngs' },
//   { label: 'Pears', value: 'pears' }
// ]

class App extends Component {
  state = { selectedFruits: [] }

  onSelectionsChange = (selectedFruits) => {
    // selectedFruits is array of { label, value }
    this.setState({ selectedFruits })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <SelectMultiple
          items={fruits}
          selectedItems={this.state.selectedFruits}
          onSelectionsChange={this.onSelectionsChange} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default App
```

Comment: by the way, checkbox you are using in your code is now deprecated according to react native docs